# New thread for every element read in from text file in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Ok so i have a program that is fully functional but i would like to multi-threaded  it to make it faster, what it does is updates a box. Right now it does one box at a time i would like to do all at same time. i done some research on it but nothing is really helping me much. here is my code below

```
 def createSSHClient(self,host,port,user,password):
       try:
         client = paramiko.SSHClient()
         client.load_system_host_keys()
         client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
         client.connect(host, port, user, password)
         return client
       except:
          print "could not connect"
          return "nothing"

 def Put(self,location, onloc, host, password, user, port):
      try:                                   
         ssh = self.createSSHClient(host, port, user, password)
         scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
         scp.put(location,onloc)
         print("Finshed Transfer")
         stdin , stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("path")
         print "going to start reboot"
         stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("path")
     except:    
         print "Lost connection"

 def push(self, Filename):
     location = Filename
     onloc = "/remote location"
     port = 22
     ct = 1
     with open("People.txt" , 'r') as inFile:    """Here is where will read in how many threads"""
           for line in inFile:
               ip,user,password = line.strip().split(',')
               self.Put(location,onloc,ip,password,user,port) """Here is where each thread should call"""
               print ("i finshed %d", ct)
               ct=+1
```

So in my comments i showed about where i get the threads and where i want the thread calls to go, can someone please help me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you looked at Fabric? It has a degree of parallelization built in and does a lot of the connection management for you already.

Comment: I could use it, but i want to learn more about python, i just started a few weeks ago and i want to learn about some basic multi threading lol

Comment: Do you have any `threading`/`multiprocessing` code then? I'd start with some examples and ask back if you have some problems implementing it.

Comment: If you already know where you want the threads to be spawned, what's stopping you from just trying it out and seeing how it goes?

Comment: Look at the examples for the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module, which show how easy it is to parallelize things like this (where each operation is independent, and doesn't require any communication besides initial arguments and a return value). If you're not using 3.2+, there's a [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) on PyPI. If you try this and get stuck, show what you tried (but not your whole code next time, just an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and where you're stuck.